# "Flash" an icon in an interface with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to emulate a behavior that is on YouTube. When switching between a "Playing" and a "Paused" state, it will flash an icon corresponding to the new state. Here is an example:
[image]

I find that there are a few "messy" ways to handle this. For example, using a `setTimeout` in `componentDidUpdate`

```
componentDidUpdate(props, { isPlaying }) {
  if (this.state.isPlaying !== isPlaying) {
    this.setState({ showIcon: true }, () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ showIcon: false });
      }, 300);
    });
  }
}
```

This seems a little superfluous, in my opinion, and I am sure there is a better way to accomplish this.

How can you briefly show an element on the screen for some amount of time?